# In-app-purchase logic in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit

i made a game  in sprite kit i thought to make full and lite one instead i made in-app purchase i thought its easy with one target, my idea is  users can play upto 99 points and if they want to play rest of the game they have to buy , as i made 2 scenes 1) mainmenu scene 2)  playscene i have buttons for IAP and restore in both scenes and  even while users playing at 99 point i add this code.if this way is wrong  which is the best way to  approach please let me know as this is my first sprite kit app

```
  if (_gameScore==99){
               //added this code in buy button as well 
            BOOL isInappSuccess = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IsInAppComplete"];

            if (!isInappSuccess) {
                //[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
                [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:INAPP_PRODUCT_ADV];
            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"InApp" message:@"Item Already Purchased" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: as andrey said your question is not clear but i think you are talking about Non-consumable products which are purchased by once. read about Non-consumable products in apple in-app-purchase guidelines i think this gonna slove ur problem

Comment: yes it is non-consumable product,i followed apple in-app purchase guidelines as well but i just want to know the logic were users can play by game upto 99 points later i want to add IAP to play rest of my game above method shows when user reached 99 points alertview pops up for IAP but how i can manage this after alertview bit confused how i can add the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//for non-consumable product you have to add following code in your application

//function checks whether user purchase a  non-consumable or not

/*
change all function acc to your game

*/

```
-(void)setDone:(Boolean)status
{
    [_urnsuserDefault setBool:status forKey:@“done];
    [_urnsuserDefault synchronize];
}

-(Boolean)getDone
{
    Boolean status=[_urnsuserDefault boolForKey:@"done"];
    return status;
}
//if user already purchase non-consumable or not (check for Restore if user purchase non-consumable product);
-(void)checkForRestore
{

    if([self getDone])
    {
        //if user successfully purchase a in app item
        UIAlertView *productAlertPur = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle:@"Restored"
                                        message:@“your” msg
                                        delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [productAlertPur show];

    }
    else
    {
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    }

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIAlertView * removedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restoration failed as %@.",error.localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [removedAlert show];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(queue.transactions.count==0){
        UIAlertView *noproductAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Restored"
                                       message:@"No Purchases to Restore"
                                       delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [noproductAlert show];
    }
    else{

        if(![self getDone])
        {
            NSString *productID = @“company.game.productid;

            [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
            UIAlertView *restoredAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Restored"
                                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Math Lab Restored successfully."]
                                          delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [restoredAlert show];
            [self viewWillAppear:YES];


            [self setDone:TRUE];
        }
   }
}
```